# Define join condition in code

Tags: nhibernate

Is it possible to code (not mapping) following query *CONDITION* for NHibernate join criteria for lazy child list?

```
...
JOIN ChildTable child ON child.ParentID = parent.ID AND <CONDITION>
```

NHibernate 2.1

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible to write that query using the criterion or the QueryOver API. Here's an example with QueryOver api

```
Child childAlias = null;     
session.QueryOver<Parent>()
                .JoinAlias(w => w.Children,
                            () => childAlias ,
                            JoinType.None,
                            Restrictions.Where<Child>(s => s.Active)
                ).List();
```

Comment: It works in NH 3. Sorry but as I wrote I need solution for NH 2.1